# Shopware: shipment costs Backend vs. Frontend

Tags: configuration, shopware

I defined the prices for shipment as follows

[image]

As you can see, for any oder with a total weight in the range [0, 1] Kg the shipment costs must be 4€. Unfortunately, for an oder of that form the shipment costs are just 3.36€

[image]

There is some workaround how can I set up the price the backendend so that 4€ would be showed in the frontend:

4€ in backend ------> 3.36€ in frontend

amount in backend    ------>  4€ in frontend

This implies: 3.36 x amount = 4 x 4 => amount = 16 / 3.36 <=> amount = 4.76€

I tested that and it really gives 4€ in the frontend, but I am not sure whether I am compatible with the most suitable way in Shopware.

I appreciate your helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it possible that 4€ is with the taxes of 19% and 3.36€ is without the taxes of 19% (on the second image you have the total of the taxes ).

Kind regards

Comment: The cost of your items (without the shipment)  is 9.60€ + 1.82€ taxes. The total of the taxes ( items + shipment ) is 2.46€. So  2.46€(total taxes) - 1.82€(taxes items) = 0.64€ ( taxes for shipment). 3.36 + 0.64 = 4.00.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation.